# Display char instead of 0 in 2D Java array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm creating a 2D array for baseball scores, and if the home team's score is greater than visiting team score after the top of the 9th, then I need that array position to display a hyphen "-" instead of zero.

```
if (eigthhomeScore > visitorScore) {
    scoreArray [1][8] = 0;
}
```

Comment: A. show your current code (enough of it that we can run it) and B. explain what you have tried. We can help if you're stuck but are not here to do your work for you.

Comment: if your `scoreArray` is an `int` array then you will not be able to store `-` there.  But you could store `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, and then if it is this value later, you could display `-`

Comment: Not expecting my work to be done for me. I've tried searching for a way to display a hyphen and not zero if 8th inning home team score is greater than visitor score after top of ninth.

Comment: @MarkL You're missing the point. Show enough of your code that we can run it and explain what you have tried in order to print a hyphen.

Comment: @MarkL surely the obvious way to "display a hyphen sometimes instead of something else" is `if(something) System.out.print("-"); else System.out.print(something else);`?

Comment: @immibis although I'm a noob, I dont think we can simply system.out.print a char inside an integer array.

Comment: @MarkL System.out.print has nothing to do with arrays. You don't "print things inside an integer array", you just print things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print hyphens instead of zeroes, then simply print hyphens instead of zeroes.

So instead of this:

```
System.out.print(scoreArray[x][y]);
```

you might write this:

```
if(scoreArray[x][y] == 0)
    System.out.print("-");
else
    System.out.print(scoreArray[x][y]);
```

Your question doesn't include the code that prints the array so I can't be more specific to your code.

Comment: I understand what you're saying and I appreciate the help. I guess I should have been more clear. I need the hyphen in one specific position (bottom of the 9th inning) when the array is displayed / printed in a scoreboard fashion. I'm just going to turn in the project as-is with the zero...

Answer (score 0):

You could either change your variable so that it is able to contains `hyphnes` by using a char or string arrays, or you could store Integer.MIN_VALUE (a magic number and not a valid baseball score), and then if it is this value later, you could display a hyphen.